# Does 萌え have the same meaning as もえ (cute)?

Tags: words

When I searched the meaning of "萌え" in the dictionary it said that this word means "sprouting, or crush (esp. on an imaginary character in manga, etc.)"

I have often heard that もえ means cute, but the meaning of this word in the dictionary is not close to "cute"

Does 萌え only refer to feelings of affection toward imaginary characters or does it have other meanings like cute?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Where did you see "moe" defined as merely "cute"?

Comment: On internet like Facebook and YouTube, I saw a lot of people using "moe" as "cute", So I thought that  "moe" is only mean cute. But when I look up on dictionary, it defined this word in other meaning too. So I got curious about this word.

Comment: Here's a whole big [article](https://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E8%90%8C%E3%81%88) on the word. "Cute" is also one of its connotations.

Answer (score 1):

萌え is the kanji for もえ, so they are the same word.

> Does 萌え only refer to feelings of affection toward imaginary characters or does it have other meanings like cute?

It can refer to real people/animals/things, but it has a very strong association with おたく. Unless you want others to know you identify as an おたく, it's best not to use it. It can have sexual connotations and would be inappropriate in some situations (like a job interview).

Comment: And it's been long since it became an outdated word even among otaku.

Comment: Thank you very much!